# Recipetool create from Git Repo

Tags: git, yocto, yocto-recipe

I am following a tutorial [How to create your first recipe and enable auto-start using systemd](https://hub.mender.io/t/how-to-create-your-first-recipe-and-enable-auto-start-using-systemd/1195/1). It is noted that

> Note that the recipe is setup to automatically download the sources from the GNU URL. The recipetool utility can also use URIs from source code management systems such as Git.

Can the recipetool accept a repo URL as an argument or do I need to create a skeleton recipe and add my git repo info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer in a book!

```
 recipetool create -V 1.0 https://github.com/OSSystems/bbexample
```

From

> Embedded Linux Development using Yocto Projects Second Edition

Page 90

Comment: Well you don't see that to often these days. Both coming back to update your question with a found answer... and finding an answer in a book.

Comment: You'll need to use -B main to specify the branch as recipetool assumes master which isn't commonly used anymore.